# Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to convert a single master setup to multi-master. Load balancer is configured to accept traffic at port 443 and one of its backend is the single master IP and its port 6443.

I used LOAD_BALANCER_IP:PORT in my kubeconfig but I encountered the x509 error. Why is this error showing, how to resolve this?

```
sudo kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint companykube.com:443 --kubernetes-version v1.21.2 --pod-network-cidr 10.244.0.0/16 --cri-socket /run/containerd/containerd.sock  --upload-certs --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=companykube.com,singlemasterIp,2ndmasterIP,3rdmasterIP --apiserver-bind-port=443
```

Comment: How did you initialize your kubeadm cluster ? It would be good to know more details on how you exactly set it up. Did you follow any specific tutorial or documentation ?

Comment: added more details

Comment: added more details at https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/103680

Comment: @letthefireflieslive, Is there any progress in this case?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak answered my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply a load balancer issue in my case. We have used nginx as load balancer and the traffic is not going through from front-end to the backend of the LB.

We have time constraint and go with the tested HAProxy config, works smoothly